# Customize a timer job to send email when an item is added to a list in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, email, timer-jobs

Need to send a mail to the Reviewer of a document ( this value is got from the Reviewer column of the library) when the document is added using timer jobs.

Kindly provide steps and code snippet for the timer job in Sharepoint 2007.

We have event receivers associated with the library. Will having timer job affect the event handlers?

There are solutions posted for Sharepoint 2010 but not for 2007.

I saw that junkrig has developed a solution and he has asked a doubt regarding this.
[Custom timer job email problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35857/custom-timer-job-email-problem)

Comment: The SMTP code in the link you provided will work to send emails. Timer jobs and event receivers can cohabit just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Louis. I have not coded Timer jobs before. Do I follow same steps provided here for 2010 in 2007 also? :  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403323/SharePoint-2010-Create-Custom-Timer-Jobs

Comment: The coding of Timer Job for 2007 is exactly as described in this article for 2010. You'll of cause not have all the nice VS support for Sulution, Feature and FeatureReceiver.

Comment: A simple workflow in Sharepoint Designer would work too, take less time to implement, and not need managed code to do.

Comment: If the job is specific to one list, then I agree with PirateEric and say that a SPD workflow would do the trick.

Comment: Yet again my question is - Can event receivers and workflow coexist in a library?
We have Item added, Item updated event on this library. Workflow has to trigger when Item is added.

Comment: I tried a simple send email workflow on a test Library.The workflow has run and shows complete. But have not received any mail. We have a SMTP server setup and have received mails with event receiver code but with the workflow, no mails! What other things do I check?